# Get products according to chosen value

Tags: opencart

I am creating a shop with Opencart 1.5.6 & I'm new to opencart & php so please help me

I searched a lot but all of results are talking about adding a filter in SORT drop down list like manufacturer ..

but **I don't want to sort**,

I added a new custom field called COLOR to product and i want to create a new drop down list contains RED,BLUE,& BLACK options and it will **get**  all the products with this chosen color.

I tried to create a drop down list like "Sort By:" one, 
but i can't because i have no experience with PHP or Opencart.

PLEASE HELP ME !! and thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

As you said you are beginner so just go through step by step

In Opencart there is a feature called filter which exactly fulfills your requirement

```
**Step1 (Creating Filter)**
Admin panel>catalog>filter>Inset a new filter
->Filter Group Name "Color".
->click on add filter and add your colors "Red, Green, Blue...."

**Step2 (Adding Filter attribute to Product)**
Admin panel>catalog>products>edit product
->under the link tab there is a filter add the filter to product you want 
eg if the product is red in color add "red" 
->Do this to all product you wanted to be filtered.

**Step3 (Adding Filter Scope to category)**
Admin panel>catalog>categories>edit category
->under the data tab there is a filter add the filter you want to be displayed like "red, green etc.."
->Do this to all category you wanted filter to be displayed.

**Step4 (Enable Filter module or setting layout)**
Admin panel>Extensions>Modules
->Find Filter and click on install
->Now Edit the filter
->click on add module 
->Set Layout to Category, Position to Content Top and Status to Enable 
->Click on Save
```

Now you are done, In category you can see the filter feature in category,

[image]

If you still find difficulties you can follow the official documentation http://docs.opencart.com/display/opencart/Filters

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ramesh, thanks bro for your effort,, 
i tried this steps before,

but the problem was Product didn't contain Color:red when i choose red checkbox then Refine search..

So i created for each product a custom field called COLOR to display it in product layout, Like SORT, LIMIT, and Price range slider...

Comment: Ramesh, m displaying products in a grid, and i have many filter attributes like(color, size, weight,....etc),, After clicking Refine Search button i needed to display each product with its row like(T-Shirt---RED---Large---300gm)..

Comment: Seems like that will be another long procedure..
If you want a Drop down just like Sort By on category
With your features like color, size, weight
You need to add extra fields on product for your color 
and you can use the exactly behavior of Sort By currently using, 
using same technique you can pass get variables to modelquery according to your extra fields like color etc

Comment: i created the custom fields,,, but i can't create a dropdown list like Sort By with the same technique.. can u help me ??

Comment: You need little deeper study in those sort method, they are not exactly dynamic, they just pass arguments to model according to need,

Comment: mmmmm i need to create a page like this:
http://www.bluenile.com/diamond-search?pt=setform&track=NavDiaSea
with any way ,, help me please